# How to write the set of all natural numbers, that can be divided by two?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to write as a mathematical expression such sentence:
x is the set of all natural numbers that can be divided by 2 without the remainder.

$\{x \in \mathbb N: What \ here? \} $

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Misery

Comment: The simplest (and to my mind the nicest) way is $\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. An alternative is $\{n\in\Bbb N:2\mid n\}$, since $a\mid b$ means '$b$ is a multiple of $a$'.

Comment: Note that if $x$ is "the set of all natural numbers that can be divided by $2$", then $x$ is the set, i.e.
$$
x = \{ n \in \mathbb N \, | \, 2 \text{ divides } n \}
$$

Comment: In other words, $x$ is the set, he's not an element of the set like you just wrote in your question. If you want the set of all elements $x \in \mathbb N$ such that blablabla, then you expect the set to look like $\{ x \in \mathbb N \, | \, \text{ blablabla here. } \}$.

Comment: I found that notation in the book saying that: {x: P(x)} means the set of those all x that have the property P, and I got confused trying to write the set as given in the question

Comment: $\{x\in\mathbb{N}:\exists y\in\mathbb{N}\; x=2y\}$

Comment: $\{n \in \mathbb N: n \text{ is even}\}$

Comment: {x∈ℕ: x = 2y for all y∈ℕ }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very typical shorthand when writing the set of natural numbers divisible by $a$ is to write $a\mathbb N = \{an \in \mathbb N\;|\; n \in \mathbb N\}$.  Clearly every natural number of the form $an$ where $n\in \mathbb N$ is divisible by $a$ and every such number arises in this way.  This follows the usual notation for [cosets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset).